# Intellij - is there autocomplete for the type of a for loop?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, format, autosuggest, jetbrains-ide

like in eclipse, if you wrote a for loop like this:

```
for (name : names)
```

eclipse auto complete would let you add the type, so you'll get:

```
for (String name : names)
```

is there a similar feature in IntelliJ?

normal auto complete CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE or CTRL+SPACE aren't working.

Answer (score 14):

You can type "iter" and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then you can select in the suggested list of all iterable variables which one to use for the loop.

This type of code generation is also available for other loops. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526746) for a list of live templates for loops.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not familiar with the equivalent eclipse feature, but the closest thing I can think of (or alternative solution) is to use postfix completion.

if you type

```
names.for
```

and select the first suggestion, it will auto-expand into

```
for (Object name : names) {

}
```

and it will automatically add the type of name for you, based on what the collection type of names is.