# Is there a way to quickly generate a foreach for an existing variable using live templates?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the following code snippet:

```
Set<Company> companiesByUserName = companyUserService.getCompaniesByUserName(username);
```

Using IntelliJ live templates, I know I can type "itco" and it will generate the following for me:

```
for (Iterator<Company> iterator = companiesByUserName.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Company next =  iterator.next();
}
```

However, how can I automatically create a foreach with the 'companiesByUserName' variable instead? So I want it to generate this automatically:

```
for (Company company: companiesByUserName) {
}
```

Because the foreach is a lot cleaner that iterating through the collection in a for loop, I generally use those instead, so would like to auto generate them if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, found out how to do it. Just type "iter" and press enter.

Answer (score 13):

There is also a new feature introduced with IJ 13, called [postfix completion](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/). With that, you can type `companiesByUserName.for` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> (and obviously much more as per your defined templates):

[image: postfix completion]

Comment: Awesome thanks. Out of interest, how did you create the gif above ?

Comment: @dleerob [Screen To Gif](http://screentogif.codeplex.com/) to capture the images and the [Presentation Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7345) IJ plugin to display the key mappings. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Type "iter" then press tab. Idea is smart enough to pick collection to iterate through.