# Abbreviations in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ comes with 2 abbreviations that I have used a lot in the past, but cannot find in PhpStorm:

```
iter    Iterate (for each..in)
itar    Iterate elements of array (traditional loop)
```

So whenever I typed `iter` and pressed tab, it generated an enhanced for-loop. How can I achieve this in PhpStorm?

Comment: It is implemented via **Live Templates** functionality. There is no such abbreviations available fro PHP -- only for JavaScript. for PHP that would be `fore` and alike. You may create your own templates or even override default ones. Just in case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PHPStorm** has `live template` so you can use it to generate several types of code snippets.

[image]

> Live templates can be used to insert frequently-used constructs into your source code, for example, loops, conditions, various declarations, print statements, tags, and so on. To expand a code snippet, type the corresponding template abbreviation and press Tab. Keep pressing Tab to jump from one variable in the template to the next. Press Shift+Tab to move to a previous variable

I think [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html) is useful and  also suggest that you read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526732/intellij-idea-generate-for-each-for-keyboard-shortcut)

for creating a new snippet you can go `settings > Editor > Live Template`